# Matching file name using Android intent-filter pathPattern

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I need to match urls ending in `/*-u.html`, e.g. `https://www.example.com/something/whatever-u.html`.

I've tried `android:pathPattern="/.*-u.html"`, which works for the above url, but it doesn't work if there's a hyphen anywhere else in the url, e.g. `https://www.example.com/some-thing/whatever-u.html`. At first I thought there was something special about the hyphen character, but then I realised the same happens with any character that follows the `.*`.

I've tried many other combinations but can't find one to reliably match the above url format. I know that PatternMatcher is limited, but I assume it should be possible to match this?

Edit: Here's a video of the issue, using the patterns suggested in  PraveenSP's answer below.

[image: Video of the pattern not being matched]

Comment: I checked it on the app links assistant tool but it didn't worked there but when i tested on real device with actual links it worked...  I suggest you to check it once on real device...

Comment: I have updated my answer with the test cases check it ...

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: Not really. I just went with the brute force approach suggested below. It looks horrible, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
android:pathPattern="/.*/.*-u.html"
```

Comment: No. This still fails if there's a `-` anywhere else in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this

```
    <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="*.yourhost.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*\\/.*-u.html"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="*.yourhost.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*-u.html"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="*.yourhost.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*\\/.*-.*-u.html"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="*.yourhost.com"
                android:pathPattern="/.*\\/.*-.*-u.html"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Tested cases : 
`https://www.example.com/some-thing/whatever-u.html`
`https://www.example.com/something/whatever-u.html`
`https://www.example.com/something/what-ever-u.html`
`https://www.example.com/some-thing/what-ever-u.html`

Comment: Not working for me. See animation I added to Question.

Comment: App Links Assistant in Android Studio

Comment: I've just tried via adb and it works for those 2 urls. It still doesn't work for other urls I need such as  https://www.example.com/something/what-ever-u.html, but since you covered the two examples I gave I'l award you the bounty.

Comment: I will try for the third one too if you need ... do you need that ... ? I will update you once I get the answer...

Comment: Many thanks. What I need is "www.examle.com/<any path or filename>-u.html"