# Matching url using Android intent-filter pathPattern

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, intentfilter, android-deep-link

I am trying to match a url using `android:pathPattern`.

When I tap a deeplink like "https://www.myhost.com/ABcTaed", I want my app to handle url ended with "ed".

In my AndroidManifest.xml. I have this `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="myhost.com" android:pathPattern="/.*ed"/>.`

With these urls work fine:

```
https://myhost.com/MgZMjed
https://myhost.com/NhANked
https://myhost.com/OiBOled
https://myhost.com/PjCPmed
```

But when the letter "e" is repeated in any place after "/" is not working.

My pathPattern syntax is wrong? What am I missing?

I was checking this question:

[Matching file name using Android intent-filter pathPattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779926/matching-file-name-using-android-intent-filter-pathpattern)

But I don't see an answer that works with my case.